# can't call map function on an array of objects in express with mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

On calling .map on an array of objects, it's throwing an error of TypeError: friends.map is not a function.

when I do it in vanilla js with the object, it works fine, but that's after I enclose the id and _id values in quotes.

is that the cause as it's of type ObjectId in Mongoose? if so, how do I fix it?

```html
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username   : String,
  firstName  : String,
  lastName   : String
 friends    : [{ id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, status: Number }]
});

app.get('/getFriends', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, 'friends')
  .populate({
    path: 'friends.id',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'username firstName lastName -_id'
  })
  .exec(function(err, friends) {
    console.log(typeof(friends))
    console.log(friends)
    friends = friends.map(function(v) {
      delete(v._id);
      delete(v.status);
      return v;
    });
    res.json(friends);
  }) 
})


events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: friends.map is not a function
```

```html
the output of console.log(friends)

[ { _id: 590bbb88858367c9bb07776e,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bba9c858367c9bb077759 },
  { _id: 590bbb95858367c9bb07776f,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbad5858367c9bb07775f },
  { _id: 590bbb9e858367c9bb077770,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbb05858367c9bb077765 },
  { _id: 590bbbaa858367c9bb077771,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbaf2858367c9bb077763 },
  { _id: 590bbbb6858367c9bb077772,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbae5858367c9bb077761 },
  { _id: 590bbbc5858367c9bb077773,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbabe858367c9bb07775d },
  { _id: 590bbbef858367c9bb077774,
    status: 2,
    id: 590bbab2858367c9bb07775b } ]
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are calling `.findOne` on the `User` model to query for a document with the `_id` in the params.

`.findOne` returns a single mongoose document (Not an array), so the second argument in the callback for `exec` should refer to the user with with that _id, with only a populated friends property. I don't quite see how you would be getting the logged output you provided. Try something along these lines:

```
app.get('/getFriends', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, 'friends')
  .populate({
    path: 'friends.id',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'username firstName lastName -_id'
  })
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    var friends = user.friends.map(function(v) {
      delete(v._id);
      delete(v.status);
      return v;
    });
    res.json(friends);
  }) 
})
```

Comment: `throw new MongooseError('Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback')`